# Worklight Adapter Call in IOS Native Passing JSON Parameter

Tags: ios, objective-c, ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-adapters

When using `JSON.parse(parameter-value)` in JavaScript, the adapter invocation is working correctly, however when doing similarly in a native iOS app, it is failing with the following error.

Javascript Adapter Call:

```
var invocationData = {
    adapter : 'TEST_ADAP',
    procedure : 'PROC1',
    parameters : [JSON.parse(A)],
};
```

Native Call:

```
json= // some json value will be come
 MyConnect *connectListener = [[MyConnect alloc] initWithController:self];
    [[WLClient sharedInstance] wlConnectWithDelegate:connectListener];
    WLProcedureInvocationData *myInvocationData = [[WLProcedureInvocationData alloc] initWithAdapterName:@"TEST" procedureName:@"test"];

    myInvocationData.parameters = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:json, nil];

    for (NSString *str in myInvocationData.parameters) {
        NSLog(@"values of account test %@",str);

    }
    PasswardPage *invokeListener = [[PasswardPage alloc] initWithController:self];
    [[WLClient sharedInstance] invokeProcedure:myInvocationData withDelegate:invokeListener];
```

Comment: Where is the error? also mention what exactly is "json" in the native part. Provide an actual example.

Comment: i was getting json this format {test = 21321312}, {test=231312}, how can i change normal format?

Comment: I don't understand you. Provide the error. Provide full code.

Comment: i need this format {test : 12345},{test2  : 232323}

Comment: You need to send an array of strings. paramater is an array of strings: http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSHS8R_7.0.0/com.ibm.worklight.apiref.doc/html/refobjc-worklight-ios/html/interface_w_l_procedure_invocation_data.html?cp=SSHS8R_7.0.0%2F9-0-1-2-0-47

Answer (score 1):

Your line

```
myInvocationData.parameters = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:json, nil];
```

is almost right.

The `parameters` property should be an `NSArray` (as you did) but the array must be made of string values - NOT a JSON object.

```
myInvocationData.parameters = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"myValue1", @"myValue2", @"myValue3", nil];
```

If the data you received is not in this format, you need to first convert it to this format. This is out of the scope of this question.

If you are not sure how to convert your existing format into a valid `NSArray`, please open a new question (tagged with Objective-C, not worklight).

Answer (score 0):

We can pass JSON as NSString in iOS Native code to invoke adapter 
Example

```
//Created Dictionary 
NSMutablec *dict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
[dict setObject:@"xyz" forKey:@"Name"];
[dict setObject:@"iOS" forKey:@"Platform"];

//Convert it to JSON Data
NSError *error;
NSData *jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:dict
                                                   options:nil
                                                     error:&error];
//JSON Data To NSString

NSString *jsonString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:jsonData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

WLProcedureInvocationData * invocationData = [[WLProcedureInvocationData alloc] initWithAdapterName:@"XYZAdapter" procedureName:@"FunctionXYZ"];

//Passing jsonString (NSString Created out of JSON Data) as array to set Parameters.

[invocationData setParameters:[NSArray arrayWithObject:jsonString]];

[[WLClient sharedInstance] invokeProcedure:invocationData withDelegate:self];
```